# SQL actualizar datos usando python (django)

Tags: python, django, sqlite

tenía una duda acerca de mi codigo usando la python shell. Yo tengo mi base de datos y quiero cambiar un valor pero cuando hago esto no me deja por alguna razon. Estaria contento si me pudieran decir que estoy haciendo mal.

```
>>>Listing.objects.get(id=1).value = 90.0
>>>Listing.objects.get(id=1).save()
>>>Listing.objects.get(id=1).value
45 #Es el valor que quiero cambiar
>>>
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estás asignando el objeto devuelto por la función `get()` a ninguna variable. Por lo tanto, el cambio que intentas hacer al atributo `value` después no lo puedes guardar.

Lo que en realidad quieres hacer es lo siguiente:

```
>>> object_ = Listing.objects.get(id=1)
>>> object_.value = 90.0
>>> object_.save()
>>> Listing.objects.get(id=1).value
90.0
```

Sin embargo, ten en cuenta que muchas veces es mejor utilizar la función `update()` sobre una queryset, cuando quieras actualizar registros de tu base de datos. Esto debido a que los cambios se realizan a nivel de SQL, haciendo un solo hit a la base de datos, en vez de hacer dos (o más) hits con la forma en que lo estás haciendo; además, puedes actualizar múltiples registros a la vez.

Con la función `update()` quedaría algo así.

```
>>> Listing.objects.filter(id=1).update(value=90.0)
>>> Listing.objects.get(id=1).value 
90.0
```